# Iterate json object array and sort it based on key with Protoype JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, prototypejs

Sorry if this question is a duplicate but I have to ask it. I am using prototype JS for reading JSON data from a file. JSON data looks like this;

```
{
    "metaData": {
        "date": "2014-10-06"
    },
    "listOf": [
        {
            "fname": "bill",
            "id": 23
        },
        {
            "fname": "tom",
            "id": 35
        },
        {
            "fname": "jerry",
            "id": 12
        },
        {
            "fname": "batman",
            "id": 68
        },
        {
            "fname": "superman",
            "id": 55
        },
        {
            "fname": "sp-m/super",
            "id": 55
        },
    ]
}
```

In my code I need to access "listOf" key/array and then I want to loop through each element and to sort those elements base on "fname" key. I am reading this data through an ajax request. Below is that code;

```
new Ajax.Request('/file.json', {
                    method:'get',
                    onSuccess: function(transport){
                        var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                        console.log(json);
                    }
                });
```

Now the VAR JSON contains the require data but I don't know how to access "listOf" data and iterate through it.

I tried to use .each function like this;

```
json.list.each(alert);
```

but it only printed " object OBJECT".

Please give me some help to resolve this issue.

P.S: Please tyr to use prototype JS for an answer but no Jquery.

Comment: Assuming that you actually used `json.listOf.each(alert)`, then that's the expected result - the same result that e.g. `alert({
            "fname": "bill",
            "id": 23
        })` would have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `listOf` collection property using its name:

```
json.listOf
```

So if you wanted to sort the array you could try using the [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) javascript method:

```
json.listOf.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.fname > b.fname) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.fname < b.fname) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});

// At this stage json.listOf will contain the sorted in-place array using the `fname` property
```

and here's a [`sample jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/b8dxzt23/) illustrating this in action.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just edited the "listOf" property with an extra value. In that the sort does not sort the elements/list properly. It place the "sp-m/super" before "superman". Any idea how this can be fix? you can try this your jsfiddle code.

Comment: Why are you surprised that `sp-m` or `super` is placed alphabetically before `superman`? That's how alphabetical sort works. If you want to perform some custom sorting that feel free to  update the anonymous function passed to the `.sort()` method to suit your custom needs.

Comment: :) I am not surprised but not understood the sorting completely. Anyway can you atleast put me in right direction that how can i put the words like "superman" before "sp-m/super". Some hints will be enough.

Comment: You wanna do inverse alphabetical order? Then just change the `if` condition. If not please specify what are the precise rules you wanna be sorting upon. Without knowing the precise rules it's quite unlikely you will be able to implement them.

Comment: What you have shown in your demo is correct. Only thing is the "listOf" property can contains values like "superman", "sv-m/ratio". And "sv-m" in sorting should come after "superman" so I want to place it ("sv-m/ratio") in the end of list.

Explanation may look incomplete or confusing but this is all I know.

Comment: Well, `sv-m/ratio` will come **after** `superman` in my demo. Did you try it? Do you understand what alphabetical sort means?

Comment: Gotcha, try using the [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function: `x.listOf.sort(function(a, b) { return a.fname.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.fname.toLowerCase()); });`

Comment: Never mind I guess I have figured out the problem and sorting too :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. I need to make the alphabets lowercase and then compare them. Thanks a lot anyway :)